# In IE Html2canvas image text is overlapped

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html2canvas

Using html2canvas i have captured the DIV in the page, in the image the content of the image are overlapped. There is no space between the text in the image. In  chrome and FF it is working fine.

JS

```
window.takeScreenShot = function() {
       html2canvas(document.getElementById('target')).then(canvas => {
         document.body.appendChild(canvas)
       });
    }
```

HTML

```
window.takeScreenShot = function() {
       html2canvas(document.getElementById('target')).then(canvas => {
         document.body.appendChild(canvas)
       });
    }
```

CSS

```
#target{
      width:300px;
      height:200px;
      background:blue;
      color:white;
      padding:10px;
    }

    button{
      display:block;
      height:20px;
      margin-top:10px;
      margin-bottom:10px;
  }
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sodofkcs/3849/)

Is there a way to make it work in IE without merging